# Maximum consecutive multiples of coprimes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, coprime

Given a set of coprimes, can we calculate a value or a limit for the maximum number of consecutive multiples of these values that can possibly occur?

Now, given the same set of coprimes, if each value initiates two sequences of multiples with different starting points, can we calculate the maximum in that case?

For example, if our set is {5, 7, 11, 13}, and multiples of 5 start at 5 and 6, multiples of 7 start at 7 and 8, multiples of 11 start at 11 and 12, and multiples of 13 start at 13 and 14, what's the maximum unbroken stretch of multiples that can occur?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.   And for clarity:  what does, e.g., "multiples of $5$ start at $5$ and $6$" mean?

Comment: trivially until the next prime?

Comment: Please rephrase,not able to understand what you mean.

Comment: In this case, $0$ and $1$ mod $5,7,11,13$, the most is twelve, for example from $335$ to $346$.  Sorry, I don't have any ideas how to do it in general.

Comment: @lulu I have computed the result for some sets. I don't know where to start with this analytically.  A sequence of multiples of 5, so 5 10 15 20 etc.  A sequence with the same spacing starting at 6, so 6 11 16 21 etc.

Comment: Still not following.  Why not edit your post to include the solution for $\{5,7,11,13\}$?   I think that example is pretty straight forward and illustrates the general principle.

Comment: And, for clarity:  I am assuming that you are looking for a consecutive list in which *each* entry is divisibly by at least one of the given set.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @lulu The idea is each element in the set produces a series of normal multiples and another identical series that is offset from the first one.  And yes, looking for a consecutive list where each entry is covered by any of the series of multiples including the offset series.

Comment: This is related to the "Jacobsthal function", if you want to look that up.

Comment: @GregMartin can you explain how it is related?

Comment: @RickyVesel "The idea is each element in the set produces ...." is not expressed in "multiples of these values". I read "multiples of $\{ 5, 7, 11, 13 \}$ as $ S = \{ 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 25, 26, \ldots \}$. $\quad$ It seems like you want both $5k$ and $5k+1$. Please express that clearly. You did subsequently mention "each value initiates two sequences of multiples ", so are we allowed to choose $ S + a, S+b$ (with obvious abuse of notation)?

Comment: Sequences $1$ and $4\pmod5$, $1$ and $3\pmod7$, $1$ and $2\pmod{11}$ and $5$ and $7\pmod{13}$ include all numbers from $1$ to $24$

Comment: plz clarify your post.

Answer (score 1):

A simple inclusion-exclusion argument says that, for an interval of $x$ numbers, with two residue classes from each of $5,7,11,13$, there must be enough contributions to fill the interval.  So, note the positive terms involve the ceiling function, and the negative terms involve the floor function:
$$x\le 2(\lceil x/5\rceil+\lceil x/7 \rceil+\lceil x/11\rceil+\lceil x/13\rceil)\\
-4(\lfloor x/35\rfloor +\lfloor x/55\rfloor+\lfloor x/65\rfloor +\lfloor x/77\rfloor + \lfloor x/91\rfloor + \lfloor x/143\rfloor) \\
+8(\lceil x/385\rceil + \lceil x/455\rceil + \lceil x/715\rceil + \lceil x/1001\rceil \\
-16\lfloor x/5005\rfloor$$
If my graph is correct, that means $x\le139$ would be the widest possible interval for this set of coprime numbers $\{5,7,11,13\}$.
A simpler calculation, that uses $\lceil z\rceil \lt z+1$ and $\lfloor z\rfloor \gt z-1$, is $$x\lt\frac{3^4-1}{\frac35\frac57\frac9{11}\frac{11}{13}}=269.629...$$
However, as I hint at in comments, the actual widest possible interval covered is $24$ numbers.  That involved a computer search through all possible sets of the eight residue classes $\{5k+a,5k+b,7k+c,7k+d,11k+e,11k+f,13k+g,13k+h\}$. There are $10\times21\times55\times78$ sets.  My routine looks at the numbers from $1$ to $10010=2(5\times7\times11\times13)$. The pattern repeats every 5005 numbers, so two cycles will find all the intervals.